# Make Camera Look at point using a world transformation matrix?

Tags: opengl, math, 3d, rotation, glm-math

Variants of this question might have been asked on this site, but none of the answers I found worked in my case.

I am trying to make a Camera look at a point. The camera has a world transformation matrix, which is used to calculate the front vector, the eye position when making the view matrix finally. My camera is treated like any other object in the scene and thus has a world transform. I want to be able to modify this world transform, and that should automatically affect the camera. I want to actually modify the world transform of this camera so that it will "LookAt" a point.

For this, I modify the Rotation term of the world transform (**R** in **T** * **S** * **R**) like this:

```
void WorldTransform::SetLookAt( float x, float y, float z ) {

    vec3 lookPoint = vec3 ( x, y, z );

    vec3 lookDir = normalize( lookPoint - m_position  );

    float lookLengthOnXZ = sqrtf( lookDir.z*lookDir.z + lookDir.x*lookDir.x );
    m_rotationX = degrees(atan2f( lookDir.y, lookLengthOnXZ ));
    m_rotationY = degrees(atan2f( lookDir.x, lookDir.z ));

    RotateAbs( m_rotationX, m_rotationY, m_rotationZ );

    UpdateMatLocal( );
}
```

Basically, I already have a function that can set the rotation (`RotateAbs()`), so I calculate the pitch, yaw and roll angles and pass them to there.

While calculating the view matrix, I just do:

```
void Camera::Update( ) {
    if (m_pTransform.m_pointer == nullptr) return;

    vec3& position = m_pTransform->GetPosition( );
    m_look         = m_pTransform->GetForward( );
    m_lookAt       = position + m_look;

    //Calculate the new matrix
    m_view = glm::lookAt( position, m_lookAt, glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.f, 0.0f ));


}
```

This sort of works, the camera starts deviating from where it should be looking at after a while. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view "look at" matrix for camera at point "eye", looking "at", i.e. mine looks like this:

```
Matrix4x4<T> & LookAt(Vec3<T> const & eye, Vec3<T> const & at, Vec3<T> const & up)
{
    auto d = Vec3<T>();
    auto u = Vec3<T>();
    auto r = Vec3<T>();

    d = Unit(at - eye);                     
    u = Unit(up);                       
    r = Unit(Cross(d, u));      
    u = Cross(r, d);

    v[0] = r[0];    v[1] = u[0];    v[2] = -d[0];   v[3] = 0;
    v[4] = r[1];    v[5] = u[1];    v[6] = -d[1];   v[7] = 0;
    v[8] = r[2];    v[9] = u[2];    v[10] = -d[2];  v[11] = 0;
    v[12] = 0;      v[13] = 0;      v[14] = 0;      v[15] = 1;

    return operator *= (Math::Translate<T>(-eye[0], -eye[1], -eye[2]));
}
```

.  With this you won't need a world matrix to move to `eye`.  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: What you posted is a function that constructs the view matrix. I already have that. My camera is treated like any other object in the scene and thus has a world transform. I want to be able to modify this world transform, and that sould automatically affect the camera.

Comment: The view matrix *is* the world transform for your camera.

Comment: I want to be able to deduce this matrix from the world transform. I want to be able to modify the world matrix to look at a point, then deduce the view matrix from there ( by taking inverse?)